# Strange shadows with Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

Any idea why I am constantly getting these random shadows and in the rendered texture using cycles and hdri for lighting? I don't get them in shading viewport.[image]

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, 
is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) 
and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing)

Comment: no, we always write the title with capitals..

Answer (score 0):

I had duplicate object underneath it self. Visibility was turned off but, it was still rendered.

Comment: maybe because of wrecked caps lock key? ;)